# How to open a URLand postdata in Safari in swift

Tags: swift, url, post

How to open a url in system default browser by using Swift as programming

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "url")!)
```

how post data to url

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot send data in POST with the function `openURL`. A valide alternative could be opening the page in a `UIWebView` and sending the POST data by `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: We want to use a service that banks do not give permission to use the Web View

Comment: @KavosKhajavi Unfortunately you don't have other way to send post data in addition to UIWebView